# How and when did gold achieve its cultural role?

Tags: prehistory, gold

How and when did gold achieve its cultural role? My assumption is that before some point there is no evidence for a human affinity for gold— and then there is. What happened?

Do any other species demonstrate an analogous affinity for this element?

I am not asking why gold had value to ancient or prehistoric peoples.

Comment: You're asking "how" gold achieved its cultural role, but you don't want to know "why" gold had value?  I'm not sure what hair you're trying to split here.

Comment: @Joe, considering this is prehistory any "why" would likely be highly subjective and drawn from secondary/tertiary sources or even the brash speculation of the question answerer. Hence, it is not very useful compared to the when or how.

Comment: This question would be difficult indeed- perhaps a bounty is in order?

Comment: How (and when) did whale bone achieve its cultural role (in Inuit culture). In other words, in which culture(s) do you refer? Gold does not have worldwide _cultural_ significance, no matter how much you may wish to believe.

Comment: How could I make it clearer that I am not asking why ancient or prehistoric peoples valued gold? I am asking when this happened(@CGCampbell I'd love to know when this affinity arose in different place) and how it happened.

Comment: I contend that this is not a duplicate.